# How do I Upgrade Elasticsearch to the latest version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

I try to run a search on my rails project and I get this error `Searchkick::UnsupportedVersionError` and `This version of Searchkick requires Elasticsearch 1.0 or greater`

I have checked all over Stackoverflow and no one seems to have this answer. Any help?

Comment: Have you tried downloading and installing the latest version of Elasticsearch?

Comment: The first place for instal/upgrade steps is on elasticsearch website directly [upgrading](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-upgrade.html)

Answer (score 0):

From searchkicks' github readme

*For Elasticsearch 0.90, use version 0.6.3 and this readme.*

Consider either updating elasticsearch on your machine, you can download it from http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/elkdownloads/, if you are using ubuntu the easiest way is to download and install DEB package, for RHEL/fedora (and similar) RPM package, for OS X either zip/tar archive and follow instructions.

Alternatively for OS X you can use

`brew install elasticsearch`

according to this http://red-badger.com/blog/2013/11/08/getting-started-with-elasticsearch/

or consider using older version of searchkick (not recommended) :)